# Increase of version number of R packages if only code outside the functions is changed

Tags: r, github, r-package

I am working on an R package that I submitted to Cran and am further developing on GitHub. I want to use [semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning); however, I am not sure how I should deal with minor changes in the code that don't affect the functions themselves. For instance, if I commit minor changes in the examples, make additional comments in the code, or change the text on the website/description file, this does not really affect the functions themselves. Should I nevertheless increase the patch-release number in the DESCRIPTION file when I commit these kinds of changes?

Comment: Yes.  In any case, it is required by the [CRAN Repository Policy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to increase it. I would just increase the patch number, see https://r-pkgs.org/lifecycle.html#sec-lifecycle-version-number